# How Authenticate with Firebase Using a Custom Authentication System in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

Normally in flutter with firebase the email field is used, but I am trying to configure it to use another field, but I have a lot of doubts about it

In this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/custom-auth, and as I understood from the documentation:

1. how to create an authentication server,
2. verify the credentials i.e. username and password,
3. generate the token,
4. send the token to our flutter app.

but it is not clear, if someone can explain how, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Firebase documentation does not present all the details on how to create an authentication server and how to generate a JSON Web Tokens (i.e. JWT) because some of the steps are out of the scope of Firebase as explained below.

As detailed in [the AdminSDK documentation on how to create Custom JWTs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens), you need to "create a server endpoint that accepts sign-in credentials" (i.e. which includes your "another field") and return to the client device (your flutter app) a custom JWT.

So you need to:

1. Setup a server that can communicate with the Firebase services exposed on the web;
2. [Implement in this server the logic to create the JWT](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk) using the Firebase Admin SDK. Note that if your server uses a language that doesn't have an official Firebase Admin SDK (Node.js, Java, Python, Go and C# at the time of writing), you can still manually create custom tokens as explained [here in the doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library).
3. Expose, via your server, an HTTPS endpoint for your app to communicate with your server, i.e. sending the sign-in credentials and receiving back the JWT.

**Steps 1 and 3 are out of the scope of Firebase.**

Then, from the app, you can sign in the user with the token by using the `signInWithCustomToken()` method, as explained in the [doc you referred to](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/custom-auth).

```
try {
    final userCredential =
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCustomToken(token);
    print("Sign-in successful.");
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    switch (e.code) {
        case "invalid-custom-token":
            print("The supplied token is not a Firebase custom auth token.");
            break;
        case "custom-token-mismatch":
            print("The supplied token is for a different Firebase project.");
            break;
        default:
            print("Unkown error.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Rasal, did you have the time to look at the proposed answer?

Comment: hi, yes, but i dont know exctaly how do it, i m building a server with javascript and node.js. when i finish i have to create the method for generate the token in my code server or in dart? and then when it gets the token have to sent it with http to the front end? do you know what i mean?

Comment: Hi, you have to generate the token in your server as explained in the documentation referred to in bullet point #2 in my answer. The you will probably use the express framework for the HTTP endpoint.